# Rule to add product after a certain product is added

Tags: commerce

We have certain products in our range that have a second product added automatically when ordered.

I have tried to setup a rule through workflows, but cannot get it to work.

I thought this would be a common question, but i cannot find any documentation on it either.

Does anyone know the rules setup for this?

Any help is much appreciated.

This is what ive tried:

```
{ 
"rules_add_second_product" : {
"LABEL" : "Add Second Product",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"WEIGHT" : "3",
"TAGS" : [ "Secondary" ],
"REQUIRES" : [ "commerce", "commerce_cart" ],
"ON" : [ "commerce_cart_product_add" ],
"IF" : [
  { "entity_exists" : {
      "type" : "commerce_product",
      "property" : "sku",
      "value" : "123456"
    }
  }
],
"DO" : [
  { "commerce_cart_product_add_by_sku" : {
      "USING" : {
        "user" : [ "site:current-user" ],
        "sku" : "654321",
        "quantity" : "1",
        "combine" : 1
      },
      "PROVIDE" : { "product_add_line_item" : { "product_add_line_item" : "Added product line item" } }
    }
  }
]
 }
}
```

Comment: Your rule looks correct however the SKU numbers are different, make sure the condition matches a valid product SKU and that that SKU is added to the cart. Hopefully the second add to cart action doesn't make the rule recurse though.

Comment: I have been able to test the conditions, by adding a redirect action. The redirect works perfect, but no second product (different sku) added to cart. The SKU should be different on the action, as it's a completely separate item that gets added to the order. Anyway to text why that particular action is not working? Thanks for your help